# Difficulties with a limit while trying to calculate " integral from 0 to 1 of x² dx".

Tags: calculus, soft-question, indefinite-integrals, riemann-sum

This is from an exercise in Stewart, *Calculus*.

I managed to express the definite integral as the limit of a Riemann sum.

After having calculated

$\Delta x = \frac 1 n$

and

- right hand sample point $x_i$ = *i-1/n)= i/n,*

I ended with the expression

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i =1}^n\left (\frac{i}{n}\right)^2 \cdot \frac 1 n$$

Calculating this product is not difficult, but I cannot manage to find the limit which seems to be 0 , which is false however.

I tried to ask the question on Symbolab , but the computer does not show steps in the limit calculation, but instead uses the evaluation theorem ( using a primitive).

Comment: ${\large \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2}=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$, and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac {i^2}{n^3}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: To be honest I can't yet , but thanks for the hint, I'll use this as a starting point.

Comment: How about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} {\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)\left(\dfrac26+\dfrac1{6n}\right)}$?